# Convert "human readable" Excel table to correct one in R (expand 1 column names over multiple columns)?

Tags: r, excel

I have a large .xlsx datasets recording density, cover and height of cauliflower, broccoli, and some other species over multiple dates during a year.

Data was created in Excel, therefore its is nicely structured to "human eyes". 
**Columns** represents plots (Plot, Frame, PlotCrop) and veggies characteristics (Cauliflower, Brocolli & Unknown), **rows** are individual subplots within a field.

BUT: **Each veggie has 3 characteristics (Density, Cover, Height), but only one column name!**

[image]

My question is, how to read this table efficiently in R?

Loading the table in R looks like this:

```
setwd("C:/fieldData")

# Read csv files
tab<-read.csv("format_question.csv", header = TRUE)
```

Results in:

```
> tab
  Date..4.16.16     X  X.1                     Cauliflower   X.2    X.3                       Broccoli   X.4    X.5 Unknown..1   X.6    X.7
1          Area            Brassica oleracea var. botrytis              Brassica oleracea var. italica                                     
2                                        # plants in a row                                        TRAE                    UNK              
3          Plot Frame Crop                         Density Cover Height                        Density Cover Height    Density Cover Height
4           114    1N   SO                               1     5      0                              1  <NA>      0          0     0      0
5           114    2N   SO                               1     5      0                              0     0      0          0     0      0
6           114    4N   SO                               2     2      0                              0     0      0          0     0      0
7           214    1N   SO                               8     5      0                              0     0      0          0     0      0
8           214    2N   SO                               7     5      0                              0     0      0          0     0      0
9           214    3N   SO                               9     5      0                              0            0          0     0      0
```

Instead I would like to see something like this, i.e. keep somehow the indication of the recorded veggie.

```
> tab
            Plot Frame Crop  Cauli.Density Cauli.Cover Cauli.Height Broc.Density Broc.Cover Broc.Height    UNK.Density UNK.Cover UNK.Height
4           114    1N   SO        1          5          0          1   <NA>         0          0          0          0
5           114    2N   SO        1          5          0          0     0          0          0          0          0
6           114    4N   SO        2          2          0          0     0          0          0          0          0
7           214    1N   SO        8          5          0          0     0          0          0          0          0
8           214    2N   SO        7          5          0          0     0          0          0          0          0
9           214    3N   SO        9          5          0          0     0          0          0          0          0
```

As I have about 40 Excels .csvs, I really would like to avoid manually copying the column names for each veggie, and make at least part of it automatic. But I don't know how?

Thank you for any suggestion!

---

Dummy table is available here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ac4dbahddmsomqp/format_question.csv?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`unpivotr`](https://github.com/nacnudus/unpivotr) might become your friend - I'm not really used to it, but to give you an idea:

---

**Edit 2018-08-01:** A simplification of the original answer, using [unpivotr](https://nacnudus.github.io/unpivotr), similar to a recipe in [Spreadsheet Munging Strategies](https://nacnudus.github.io/spreadsheet-munging-strategies/pivot-simple.html#two-clear-rows-of-text-column-headers-left-aligned), kindly provided by @nacnudus, the author of the package and the recipe book:

```
library(unpivotr)
library(tidyverse)

# from the OP's dropbox https://www.dropbox.com/s/ac4dbahddmsomqp/format_question.csv?dl=1
csv_text <-
"Date  4/16/18,,,Cauliflower,,,Broccoli,,,Unknown #1,,
Area,,,Brassica oleracea var. botrytis,,,Brassica oleracea var. italica,,,,,
,,,# plants in a row,,,BRAS,,,UNK ,,
Plot,Frame,PlotCrop,Density,Cover,Height,Density,Cover,Height,Density,Cover,Height
114,1N,SO,1,5,0,1,NA,0,0,0,0
114,2N,SO,1,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
114,4N,SO,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
214,1N,SO,8,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
214,2N,SO,7,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
214,3N,SO,9,5,0,0,,0,0,0,0 "

csv_text %>%
  read_csv(col_names = FALSE) %>%
  as_cells() %>%
  dplyr::filter(!between(row, 2L, 3L)) %>%
  behead("W", "Plot") %>%
  behead("W", "Frame") %>%
  behead("W", "PlotCrop") %>%
  behead("NNW", "Name") %>%
  behead("N", "metric") %>%
  select(-data_type, -col) %>%
  spread(metric, chr) %>%
  select(-row)
#> # A tibble: 18 x 7
#>    Plot  Frame PlotCrop Name        Cover Density Height
#>    <chr> <chr> <chr>    <chr>       <chr> <chr>   <chr> 
#>  1 114   1N    SO       Broccoli    <NA>  1       0     
#>  2 114   1N    SO       Cauliflower 5     1       0     
#>  3 114   1N    SO       Unknown #1  0     0       0     
#>  4 114   2N    SO       Broccoli    0     0       0     
#>  5 114   2N    SO       Cauliflower 5     1       0     
#>  6 114   2N    SO       Unknown #1  0     0       0     
#>  7 114   4N    SO       Broccoli    0     0       0     
#>  8 114   4N    SO       Cauliflower 2     2       0     
#>  9 114   4N    SO       Unknown #1  0     0       0     
#> 10 214   1N    SO       Broccoli    0     0       0     
#> 11 214   1N    SO       Cauliflower 5     8       0     
#> 12 214   1N    SO       Unknown #1  0     0       0     
#> 13 214   2N    SO       Broccoli    0     0       0     
#> 14 214   2N    SO       Cauliflower 5     7       0     
#> 15 214   2N    SO       Unknown #1  0     0       0     
#> 16 214   3N    SO       Broccoli    <NA>  0       0     
#> 17 214   3N    SO       Cauliflower 5     9       0     
#> 18 214   3N    SO       Unknown #1  0     0       0
```

---

**The original answer:**

```
library(unpivotr)
library(tidyverse)
download.file("https://www.dropbox.com/s/ac4dbahddmsomqp/format_question.csv?dl=1", tf<-tempfile(fileext = ".csv"))
df <- tf %>% 
  read_csv(col_names = FALSE) %>% 
  tidy_table() %>% 
  filter(!row %in% 2:3) %>% 
  behead("NNW", "a") %>% 
  behead("N", "b") %>% 
  unite("header", a, b) %>% 
  select(-data_type, -col) %>%
  spread(header, chr) %>% 
  rename_at(vars(starts_with("Date")), ~sub("[^_]+_(.*)", "\\1", .x)) %>% 
  select(-row) %>% select(Frame:PlotCrop, everything())
glimpse(df)
# Observations: 6
# Variables: 12
# $ Frame                <chr> "1N", "2N", "4N", "1N", "2N", "3N"
# $ Plot                 <chr> "114", "114", "114", "214", "214", "214"
# $ PlotCrop             <chr> "SO", "SO", "SO", "SO", "SO", "SO"
# $ Broccoli_Cover       <chr> NA, "0", "0", "0", "0", NA
# $ Broccoli_Density     <chr> "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"
# $ Broccoli_Height      <chr> "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"
# $ Cauliflower_Cover    <chr> "5", "5", "2", "5", "5", "5"
# $ Cauliflower_Density  <chr> "1", "1", "2", "8", "7", "9"
# $ Cauliflower_Height   <chr> "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"
# $ `Unknown #1_Cover`   <chr> "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"
# $ `Unknown #1_Density` <chr> "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"
# $ `Unknown #1_Height`  <chr> "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"
```

Comment: Wow, that's looks awesome, I'll definitely check the 'unpivotr' library! However, when I run your solution, I have an Error: Error in function_list[[i]](value) : could not find function "behead". I have updated R studio and all packages, but I still have the error. I have R Studio version 3.3.2

Comment: You need the development version from github, not the one from cran: `devtools::install_github("nacnudus/unpivotr", build_vignettes = TRUE)`.

Comment: Awesome!! I took me installing more packages: 'tidyxl', 'yaml' and 'maptools' but seems working now :-DD